# semidirect product and homomorphisms which doesn't make any sense

Tags: group-theory

In describing a semidirect product I haven't understood if a homomorphism is well-defined

It says that if $G$is a semidirect product between K and Q then there is a homomorphism $\theta:Q\rightarrow Aut(K)$defined by $\theta_x=\gamma_x|K$,that is ,for all $x\in Q,a\in K,\theta_x(a)=xax^{-1}$
Now,I am aware that x and a are not multiplied under the group G but how is this operation between,$x$ and $a$ and $x^{-1}$defined,that's what I want to know.

This is quoted from the book of **Joseph Rotman** "An introduction to the theory of groups",page 169.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, no: the product $\;xax^{-1}\;$ does happen within the group G from which both $\;Q, K\;$ are subgroups. Observe that $\;K\lhd G\iff \;\forall\,x\in G\;\forall\,a\in K\;,\;\;xax^{-1}\in K\;$ and thus conjugation on $\;K\;$  (by an element in $\;G\;$!) keeps us in $\;K\;$ ...There is a "slgiht" difference if the semidirect product is exterior and not interior, but this comes, I believe, later.

Comment: so I get that the hypothesis includes the fact that $Q\leq G$,which is not mentioned in the book on that page!

Comment: but lemma 7.20 in page 168 mentions *explicitly* that $\;Q,K\le G\;$ ,and I think that in page 169 we're still under that assumption.

Comment: you're very much likely right!Thanks again for help!